# How to mock getQueryResult in hyperledger fabric MockStub

Tags: mocking, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am writing GO chaincode with Hyperledger Fabric 1.0 version. 
It appears getQueryResult is not implemented in MockStub.

How could I implement it for my unit test I am writing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is work in progress to enable support for this API in MockStub, see [FAB-5015](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-5015) and [Gerrit CR](https://gerrit.hyperledger.org/r/#/c/16325/) currently under review. Meanwhile you might probably consider to leverage [Testify](https://github.com/stretchr/testify) mocking framework to write your unit tests.